# Developer tools able to set httponly cookies = security issue?

Tags: cookies, firebug, security

Recently I noticed that it is possible to change the value of a cookie which is set to httponly via Firebug. From what I have read the httponly flag should stop any kind of client side script from accessing or altering the value of such a cookie, in [supporting browsers](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly#Browsers_Supporting_HttpOnly). If you create a cookie as httponly, however, then use Firebug 1.10 Beta with the new Cookies panel, you can actually change the value of this cookie. This means that anyone who intercepts a request or who has managed to get spyware onto the users computer which feeds back cookie / website information can access a site logged in as the user by changing any session related cookies to match that of the original user.

I tried to raise this on the [Firebug Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/firebug) a few hours ago but it hasn't been allowed yet. Does anyone else consider this to be a major security flaw in Firebug? It may be present in Chrome or IE dev tools too but I haven't checked.

Answer (score 2):

No, I do not think that this is a security flaw.

Firebug runs, just like the rest of the Firefox UI, on higher privilegues than the site javascript code. Thus it has access to the cookies.

Also, someone installing spyware or being able to intercept the request has already won anyways. Such a flag will not protect you against [Man-In-The-Middle (MITM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attacks or browser-external spyware (which could just read the directories of the browser).

The impact of MITM can be mitigiated by using https.

Comment: Hi Jonas, thanks for your answer. I'm aware that such a flag will not *prevent* attacks - but it makes it a lot easier. All you need is a piece of spyware and you can get the names / values of the cookies you need to add using Firebug. I'm just a bit concerned that it makes it a little too easy. I understand there are many other techniques a hacker could use, but the fewer ways there are the better in my mind.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy I bet firebug does not expose any API which is not already exposed by Firefox. So the spyware does not have an easier way just because Firebug is installed. And again, a piece of spyware can easily just read the files on disk. On-site javascript should be unable to access the cookie APIs of Firebug. If that would be different, it would be a leak of course.

Comment: Ok I see your point - I wasn't thinking about the hacker having an application which would set the cookies for him - I was thinking about the hacker manually changing the cookie themselves as they don't necessarily know the names, but now I realise they would just copy all of them using their own application, regardless of names. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: So is there any way to get around this? Something we could store in the DB or something which would prevent a hacker being able to copy this and access the users session? I know an IP is out of the question, as this is easy to spoof. I've noticed on Salesforce they've managed to achieve something whereby it isn't possible to copy all the cookies and access the session but I have no idea how they've done it.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy Anything which is ever on the client side is basically out of your control. You could try to sign the cookies contents cryptographically using private keys, but I'm not sure that would help in your case.