# console.log HttpOnly Cookies

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-console

Some cookies are marked as HttpOnly. See Chrome developer tools > resources > cookies > http column, does a checkmark here indicate HttpOnly cookie?

If I use this code inside the debug console to get all cookies:

```
console.log(document.cookie)
```

Then it gives me everything except the HttpOnly cookies, which because my code is running inside the javascript environment and the design of HttpOnly is to hide it from the javascript environment.

Is there another option to use the Chrome console to get all the cookies?

I am hoping to get this in the same format as the above line of code produces.

Comment: Yes, that checkmark means it's HttpOnly.

Comment: @Steve He seems to be hoping there's something that can be used in console JS even though it's not allowed in application JS.

Comment: @Barmar I assumed that to be true but is there a way to untick it from the console just like you can untick it manually in application?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible with DevTools. But there's an extension EditThisCookie that allows you to uncheck it.

Comment: @Barmar Oh yeah I have heard of that but if you use dev tools to go to application settings you can manually uncheck httponly without any extensions.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your last comment. I think of console and DevTools as the same thing.

Comment: If you right-click on the cookie in the HttpOnly field, there is a menu that has an option for `Edit "HttpOnly"`

Comment: If there's a way to access them from the console, I don't know what it is.

Comment: In general, the console runs in the same environment as the application JS.

Comment: @Steve Yea but I need it to be done using only a console command.

Comment: @Barmar True it may not be possible.

Comment: You can use Firebug console: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273634/developer-tools-able-to-set-httponly-cookies-security-issue